# Identifying multiple peaks and trough in the data set of % utilization values ranging between 1 - 100

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of data in one column of an Excel sheet.

I want to identify peaks and troughs in that dataset having % utilization values that are ranging between 1 - 100.

The nature of data is such that once a peak is achieved it will head downwards to a trough point and then again head upward for a peak and so on.

Can we identify multiple peaks and trough in the data set using an Excel formula or VBA code?

[image]

Comment: Graph it and count them?

Comment: get the difference between two consecutive cells and put a 1 if positive, -1 if negative. Then look for the change points...

Comment: In your sample data, based on a simple definition there are many more peaks and troughs.  Do you want these identified as well, or is there some more complex criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Peaks:

```
=LET(
   data; B3:B50;
   (OFFSET(data;1;0)<data) * (OFFSET(data;-1;0)<data))
```

Troughs:

```
=LET(
   data; B3:B50;
   (OFFSET(data;1;0)>data) * (OFFSET(data;-1;0)>data))
```

`Data` is the range of numbers **except first and last** one. I suppose it's something like `B3:B50` in your case. So put the formula in `C3` and look for 1's along the column `C` or select `B3:B50` and apply the next formula for conditional formatting:

```
=AND(OFFSET(B3;1;0)>B3);OFFSET(B3;-1;0)>B3))
```